# bootstrap card 6 images in one line

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

hello i am trying to create a responsive card with bootstrap that includes 6 images in 1 line but i am sick of trying and the best i could to was 4 in one line here is my codes

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;

  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 70rem;

}

.cols{

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.col{

  width: calc(25% - 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container1{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
 .front,
.back{
  word-wrap: break-word;
 
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    

  background-size: 200px 400px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 372px;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
text-overflow: ellipsis;


  
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .front,
.back{
  word-wrap: break-word;
 
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    

  background-size: 200px 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
}


@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .img-card {
   height: 400px;border-radius: 10px;width: 300px
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .img-card {
    height: 300px;border-radius: 10px;width: 300px
  }
}
.back{
    background-color: #000;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);

  

}

.front:after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    opacity: .3;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.container1:hover .front,
.container1:hover .back{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
}

.back{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;


}

.inner{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
            transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-perspective: inherit;
            perspective: inherit;
    z-index: 2;

}

.container1 .back{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

}

.container1 .front{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container1:hover .back{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container1:hover .front{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front .inner p{
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;

}

.front .inner p:after{
  content: '';
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #C6D4DF;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: -.75rem;

}

.front .inner span{
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 300;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 64rem){
  .col{
    width: calc(33.333333% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 48rem){
  .col{
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 32rem){
  .col{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
  }
}



.form-gradient .header {
  border-top-left-radius: .3rem;
  border-top-right-radius: .3rem;
}
.form-gradient input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fd9267;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #fd9267;
}
.form-gradient input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) + label {
  color: #4f4f4f;
}
.form-gradient textarea.md-textarea:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fd9267;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #fd9267;
}
.form-gradient .md-form textarea.md-textarea:focus:not([readonly])+label {
  color: #4f4f4f;
}


.form-dark .md-form label {
  color: #fff;
}
.form-dark input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00C851;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #00C851;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #00C851;
}
.form-dark input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) + label {
  color: #fff;
}
.form-dark textarea.md-textarea:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00C851;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #00C851;
  color: #fff;
}
.form-dark textarea.md-textarea  {
  color: #fff;
}
.form-dark .form-control, .form-dark .form-control:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
.form-dark .md-form textarea.md-textarea:focus:not([readonly])+label {
  color: #fff;
}

 .navbar-brand  {


        background: url(../../src/img/logo.png) center / contain no-repeat;
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
    }


select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0 !important;
  background: #2c3e50;
  background-image: none;
}
/* Remove IE arrow */
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
/* Custom Select */
.select {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 20em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  background: #2c3e50;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
select {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Arrow */
.select::after {
  content: '\25BC';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background: #34495e;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
  -o-transition: .25s all ease;
  transition: .25s all ease;
}
/* Transition */
.select:hover::after {
  color: #f39c12;
}

.addimg{
max-width:100%;width: 1000px;height: 120px

}
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Parallax Flipping Cards</h1>
  <div class="cols">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-3 col-6" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="container1">
                    <div class="front">
           <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <p>Diligord</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">
                          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-3 col-6" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="container1">
                    <div class="front">
           <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <p>Diligord</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">
                          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-3 col-6" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="container1">
                    <div class="front">
           <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <p>Diligord</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">
                          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-3 col-6" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="container1">
                    <div class="front">
           <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <p>Diligord</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">
                          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-3 col-6" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="container1">
                    <div class="front">
           <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <p>Diligord</p>
              <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="inner">
                          <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

here is an image of how it looks
[image: img] like you see there is a big gap i want to fill it with more pictures but no matter what i tried did not work can any one help me with this

Comment: You should copy the resulting HTML, because the code you posted here doesn't generate.

Comment: @MihailMinkov i changed it to html maybe i did not close some divs but the result is same

Comment: You should read up on how Bootstrap's grid works. You need to use columns within rows, and each row is based on 12 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to show bootstrap card 6 images in one line

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;

  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 70rem;

}

.cols{

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.col{

  width: calc(25% - 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container1{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
 .front,
.back{
  word-wrap: break-word;
 
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    

  background-size: 200px 400px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 372px;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
text-overflow: ellipsis;


  
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .front,
.back{
  word-wrap: break-word;
 
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    

  background-size: 200px 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
}


@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .img-card {
   height: 400px;border-radius: 10px;width: 300px
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .img-card {
    height: 300px;border-radius: 10px;width: 300px
  }
}
.back{
    background-color: #000;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #cedce7 0%,#596a72 100%);

  

}

.front:after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    opacity: .3;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.container1:hover .front,
.container1:hover .back{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    -o-transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
}

.back{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;


}

.inner{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
            transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-perspective: inherit;
            perspective: inherit;
    z-index: 2;

}

.container1 .back{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

}

.container1 .front{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container1:hover .back{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
          transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container1:hover .front{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front .inner p{
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;

}

.front .inner p:after{
  content: '';
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #C6D4DF;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: -.75rem;

}

.front .inner span{
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 300;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 64rem){
  .col{
    width: calc(33.333333% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 48rem){
  .col{
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 32rem){
  .col{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
  }
}



.form-gradient .header {
  border-top-left-radius: .3rem;
  border-top-right-radius: .3rem;
}
.form-gradient input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fd9267;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #fd9267;
}
.form-gradient input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) + label {
  color: #4f4f4f;
}
.form-gradient textarea.md-textarea:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fd9267;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #fd9267;
}
.form-gradient .md-form textarea.md-textarea:focus:not([readonly])+label {
  color: #4f4f4f;
}


.form-dark .md-form label {
  color: #fff;
}
.form-dark input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00C851;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #00C851;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #00C851;
}
.form-dark input[type=text]:focus:not([readonly]) + label {
  color: #fff;
}
.form-dark textarea.md-textarea:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00C851;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #00C851;
  color: #fff;
}
.form-dark textarea.md-textarea  {
  color: #fff;
}
.form-dark .form-control, .form-dark .form-control:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
.form-dark .md-form textarea.md-textarea:focus:not([readonly])+label {
  color: #fff;
}

 .navbar-brand  {


        background: url(../../src/img/logo.png) center / contain no-repeat;
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
    }


select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0 !important;
  background: #2c3e50;
  background-image: none;
}
/* Remove IE arrow */
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
/* Custom Select */
.select {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 20em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  background: #2c3e50;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
select {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Arrow */
.select::after {
  content: '\25BC';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background: #34495e;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
  -o-transition: .25s all ease;
  transition: .25s all ease;
}
/* Transition */
.select:hover::after {
  color: #f39c12;
}

.addimg{
max-width:100%;width: 1000px;height: 120px

}
```

```html
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Parallax Flipping Cards</h1>
      <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="container1">
                        <div class="front">
               <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <p>Diligord</p>
                  <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <div class="inner">
                              <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            
                </div><div class="col-md-4" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="container1">
                        <div class="front">
               <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <p>Diligord</p>
                  <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <div class="inner">
                              <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            
                </div><div class="col-md-4" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="container1">
                        <div class="front">
               <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <p>Diligord</p>
                  <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <div class="inner">
                              <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            
                </div>   </div>  </div> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-4" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="container1">
                        <div class="front">
               <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <p>Diligord</p>
                  <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <div class="inner">
                              <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            
                </div><div class="col-md-4"  ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="container1">
                        <div class="front">
               <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <p>Diligord</p>
                  <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <div class="inner">
                              <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div><div class="col-md-4" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="container1">
                        <div class="front">
               <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="../../src/upload/posts/<?php echo $img; ?>">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <p>Diligord</p>
                  <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <div class="inner">
                              <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit c.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```